# Select mysql com COUNT e GROUP BY MONTH

Tags: mysql, select, data, group-by, count

Ola,

Estou tentando unir a informações de duas tabelas para gerar um gráfico, preciso contar o total de registro consultas1 e consultas2 e agrupar por mes:

Atualmente tenho essse retorno:

**consultas1:**

```
MariaDB [logview]> SELECT MONTH(data) as MES, COUNT(id_consulta) as TOTAL1 FROM consultas1 group by MONTH(data);
+------+--------+
| MES  | TOTAL1 |
+------+--------+
|    1 |    158 |
|    2 |    125 |
|    3 |     84 |
|    4 |    227 |
|    5 |    117 |
|    6 |    117 |
|    7 |    167 |
|    8 |    170 |
|    9 |     86 |
|   10 |    165 |
|   11 |    164 |
|   12 |    186 |
+------+--------+
```

**consultas2**

```
MariaDB [logview]> SELECT MONTH(data) as MES, COUNT(id_consulta) as TOTAL1 FROM consultas2 group by MONTH(data);
+------+--------+
| MES  | TOTAL1 |
+------+--------+
|    8 |      9 |
+------+--------+
```

**Resultado esperado:**

```
+------+--------+--------+
| MES  | TOTAL1 | TOTAL2 |
+------+--------+--------+
|    1 |    158 |    0   |
|    2 |    125 |    0   |
|    3 |     84 |    0   |
|    4 |    227 |    0   |
|    5 |    117 |    0   |
|    6 |    117 |    0   |
|    7 |    167 |    0   |
|    8 |    170 |    9   |
|    9 |     86 |    0   |
|   10 |    165 |    0   |
|   11 |    164 |    0   |
|   12 |    186 |    0   |
+------+--------+--------+
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/462617/uni%C3%A3o-de-selects-para-retornar-apenas-1-consulta

Answer (score 0):

Tente com uma junção entre as tabelas:

```
SELECT  MONTH(COALESCE(consultas1.data, consultas2.data)) as MES, 
            COALESCE(COUNT(consultas1.id_consulta), 0) as TOTAL1, 
            COALESCE(COUNT(consultas2.id_consulta), 0) as TOTAL2 
FROM consultas1 FULL OUTER JOIN consultas2 ON (MONTH(consultas1.data) = MONTH(consultas2.data))
GROUP BY 1;
```

Dependendo da particularidade de sua tabela consultas1 (se for ela que define quais meses considerar) você pode utilizar LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'OUTER JOIN

Comment: Veja: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Comment: Parece que no MariaDB não se utiliza o FULL na junção: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/join-syntax/

Comment: Você pode implementar o funcionamento do FULL OUTER JOIN fazendo um UNION de um LEFT OUTER JOIN com um RIGHT OUTER JOIN mas, como já havia comentado, você tem que verificar se isso é efetivamente necessário de acordo com os seus dados. Para o exemplo apresentado bastaria um LEFT OUTER JOIN (a tabela consultas1 contém todos os meses a serem considerados).