# União de select's para retornar apenas 1 consulta

Tags: sql, select

Precisamos efetuar as seguintes consultas em apenas 1 select:

1º SELECT

```
SELECT SUM(FAPEDIDO.TOTAL_PEDIDO) AS TOTAL_CAR,
            FAPEDIDO.CD_REPRESENTANT COD_REPRESENTANTE,
            GEEMPRES.NOME_COMPLETO REPRESENTANTE
FROM FAPEDIDO,GEEMPRES
WHERE FAPEDIDO.CD_REPRESENTANT = GEEMPRES.CD_EMPRESA
AND FAPEDIDO.CONTROLE LIKE '02'
AND FAPEDIDO.DT_PEDIDO BETWEEN TO_DATE(:data_posicao_sintetica_inicial, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE(:data_posicao_sintetica_final, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
GROUP BY GEEMPRES.NOME_COMPLETO,FAPEDIDO.CD_REPRESENTANT
```

2º SELECT

```
SELECT SUM(FANFISCA.TOTAL_NF) AS TOTAL_FAT,
            FANFISCA.CD_REPRESENTANT COD_REPRESENTANTE,
            GEEMPRES.NOME_COMPLETO REPRESENTANTE
FROM FANFISCA,GEEMPRES
WHERE GEEMPRES.CD_EMPRESA = FANFISCA.CD_REPRESENTANT
AND FANFISCA.DT_EMISSAO BETWEEN TO_DATE(:data_posicao_sintetica_inicial, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE(:data_posicao_sintetica_final, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
AND FANFISCA.ESPECIE_NOTA LIKE 'S'
AND FANFISCA.CFOP BETWEEN '5101' AND '6404'
GROUP BY FANFISCA.CD_REPRESENTANT, GEEMPRES.NOME_COMPLETO
```

3º SELECT

```
SELECT SUM(FAPEDIDO.TOTAL_PEDIDO) AS TOTAL_PED,
            FAPEDIDO.CD_REPRESENTANT COD_REPRESENTANTE,
            GEEMPRES.NOME_COMPLETO REPRESENTANTE
FROM FAPEDIDO,GEEMPRES
WHERE FAPEDIDO.CD_REPRESENTANT = GEEMPRES.CD_EMPRESA
AND FAPEDIDO.CONTROLE BETWEEN '05' AND '15'
AND FAPEDIDO.DT_PEDIDO BETWEEN TO_DATE(:data_posicao_sintetica_inicial, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE(:data_posicao_sintetica_final, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
GROUP BY GEEMPRES.NOME_COMPLETO, FAPEDIDO.CD_REPRESENTANT
```

Precisamos retornar uma consulta em tabela dessa forma:
[image: Retorno das consultas]

**ALGUMA IDEIA DE COMO PODEMOS ELABORAR ESSE SELECT PARA RETORNAR A TABELA?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma solução pode ser por UNION , estas soluções podem gerar queries lentas todavia.

```
SELECT SUM(TOTAL_CAR) TOTAL_CAR,
       SUM(TOTAL_FAT) TOTAL_FAT,
       SUM(TOTAL_PED) TOTAL_PED,
       COD_REPRESENTANTE,
       REPRESENTANTE
FROM
(       
SELECT      SUM(FAPEDIDO.TOTAL_PEDIDO) AS TOTAL_CAR,
            0 AS TOTAL_FAT,
            0 AS TOTAL_PED,
            FAPEDIDO.CD_REPRESENTANT COD_REPRESENTANTE,
            GEEMPRES.NOME_COMPLETO REPRESENTANTE
FROM FAPEDIDO,GEEMPRES
WHERE FAPEDIDO.CD_REPRESENTANT = GEEMPRES.CD_EMPRESA
AND FAPEDIDO.CONTROLE LIKE '02'
AND FAPEDIDO.DT_PEDIDO BETWEEN TO_DATE(:data_posicao_sintetica_inicial, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE(:data_posicao_sintetica_final, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
GROUP BY GEEMPRES.NOME_COMPLETO,FAPEDIDO.CD_REPRESENTANT
UNION ALL
SELECT      0 AS TOTAL_CAR,
            SUM(FANFISCA.TOTAL_NF) AS TOTAL_FAT,            
            0 AS TOTAL_PED,
            FANFISCA.CD_REPRESENTANT COD_REPRESENTANTE,
            GEEMPRES.NOME_COMPLETO REPRESENTANTE
FROM FANFISCA,GEEMPRES
WHERE GEEMPRES.CD_EMPRESA = FANFISCA.CD_REPRESENTANT
AND FANFISCA.DT_EMISSAO BETWEEN TO_DATE(:data_posicao_sintetica_inicial, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE(:data_posicao_sintetica_final, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
AND FANFISCA.ESPECIE_NOTA LIKE 'S'
AND FANFISCA.CFOP BETWEEN '5101' AND '6404'
GROUP BY FANFISCA.CD_REPRESENTANT, GEEMPRES.NOME_COMPLETO
UNION ALL
SELECT      0 AS TOTAL_CAR,
            0 AS TOTAL_FAT,
            SUM(FAPEDIDO.TOTAL_PEDIDO) AS TOTAL_PED,
            FAPEDIDO.CD_REPRESENTANT COD_REPRESENTANTE,
            GEEMPRES.NOME_COMPLETO REPRESENTANTE
FROM FAPEDIDO,GEEMPRES
WHERE FAPEDIDO.CD_REPRESENTANT = GEEMPRES.CD_EMPRESA
AND FAPEDIDO.CONTROLE BETWEEN '05' AND '15'
AND FAPEDIDO.DT_PEDIDO BETWEEN TO_DATE(:data_posicao_sintetica_inicial, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE(:data_posicao_sintetica_final, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
GROUP BY GEEMPRES.NOME_COMPLETO, FAPEDIDO.CD_REPRESENTANT
) VIRTUAL 
GROUP BY COD_REPRESENTANTE,
       REPRESENTANTE
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado!
Funcionou perfeito amigo.

Answer (score 1):

Nota-se que o **COD_REPRESENTANTE** é sempre o mesmo e que você tem o intuito de buscar 3 informações de um mesmo código só que em tabelas distintas, recomendo utilizar o conceito de **SUBSELECT** e utilizar **LEFT JOIN** para unificar as informações, segue exemplo:

```
SELECT cons1.COD_REPRESENTANTE, cons1.REPRESENTANTE, cons3.TOTAL_PED, cons2.TOTAL_FAT, cons1.TOTAL_CAR

--CONSULTA 1 (TOTAL_FAT)
FROM(SELECT SUM(FANFISCA.TOTAL_NF) AS TOTAL_FAT,
     FANFISCA.CD_REPRESENTANT COD_REPRESENTANTE,
     GEEMPRES.NOME_COMPLETO REPRESENTANTE
     FROM FANFISCA,GEEMPRES
     WHERE GEEMPRES.CD_EMPRESA = FANFISCA.CD_REPRESENTANT
     AND FANFISCA.DT_EMISSAO BETWEEN TO_DATE(:data_posicao_sintetica_inicial, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE(:data_posicao_sintetica_final, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
     AND FANFISCA.ESPECIE_NOTA LIKE 'S'
     AND FANFISCA.CFOP BETWEEN '5101' AND '6404'
     GROUP BY FANFISCA.CD_REPRESENTANT, GEEMPRES.NOME_COMPLETO) cons1

--CONSULTA 2 (TOTAL_CAR)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT SUM(FAPEDIDO.TOTAL_PEDIDO) AS TOTAL_CAR,
                FAPEDIDO.CD_REPRESENTANT COD_REPRESENTANTE,
                GEEMPRES.NOME_COMPLETO REPRESENTANTE
    FROM FAPEDIDO,GEEMPRES
    WHERE FAPEDIDO.CD_REPRESENTANT = GEEMPRES.CD_EMPRESA
    AND FAPEDIDO.CONTROLE LIKE '02'
    AND FAPEDIDO.DT_PEDIDO BETWEEN TO_DATE(:data_posicao_sintetica_inicial, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE(:data_posicao_sintetica_final, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
    GROUP BY GEEMPRES.NOME_COMPLETO,FAPEDIDO.CD_REPRESENTANT) cons2
            
ON cons1.COD_REPRESENTANTE = cons2.COD_REPRESENTANTE

--CONSULTA 3 (TOTAL_PED)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT SUM(FAPEDIDO.TOTAL_PEDIDO) AS TOTAL_PED,
                        FAPEDIDO.CD_REPRESENTANT COD_REPRESENTANTE,
                        GEEMPRES.NOME_COMPLETO REPRESENTANTE
            FROM FAPEDIDO,GEEMPRES
            WHERE FAPEDIDO.CD_REPRESENTANT = GEEMPRES.CD_EMPRESA
            AND FAPEDIDO.CONTROLE BETWEEN '05' AND '15'
            AND FAPEDIDO.DT_PEDIDO BETWEEN TO_DATE(:data_posicao_sintetica_inicial, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE(:data_posicao_sintetica_final, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
            GROUP BY GEEMPRES.NOME_COMPLETO, FAPEDIDO.CD_REPRESENTANT) cons3
            
ON cons1.COD_REPRESENTANTE = cons3.COD_REPRESENTANTE
```

Para cada resultado utilizei o **SUBSELECT** para "simular" como fosse uma tabela existente, depois cruzei através do **LEFT JOIN** para trazer os resultados em uma unica linha.

Utilizei o **LEFT JOIN** devido que nem todos as consultas contem resultados para todos os representantes.

Comment: A consulta funcionou mas retornou apenas 1 representante, encaminho abaixo um print do retorno.
https://imgur.com/KEHC4fs
Alguma ideia de como podemos retornar a consulta completa?

Comment: Pe4squise pela diferença entre os diversos tipos de JOIN. Considerando que estes 0 indicam a inexistência deste COD_REPRESENTANTE  na tabela associada FULL OUTER JOIN, ou mesmo LEFT OUTER JOIN deve atender (algum destes valores sempre existe?). Uma observação: UNION define uma operação em SQL que não é a que informou que deseja.

Comment: Adair, todas as consultas não possuem resultados para o representante, no caso utilize o LEFT JOIN no lugar do INNER JOIN, vou alterar o que fiz para você.

Comment: Alterado a resposta que te dei para o LEFT JOIN, com explicação do porque utilize o LEFT JOIN

Comment: Como eu vi parece que todos tem o faturado, no caso o resultado do faturado deve pertencer ao primeiro subselect, devido a estrutura do left join, mas como o nosso amigo anonimo disse, talvez a melhor opção é o OUTER JOIN, mas o certo é utilizar a tabela que contém mais dados no primeiro subslect (no caso o que contenha todos os representantes) ou a propria tabela de representantes.

Comment: Editei com a utilização do left join correta.

Comment: Pessoal, muito obrigado, funcionou perfeito!
Vlw msm pela ajuda, agora consegui entender a diferença entre esses operadores.